# jqGrid and jQuery.get()

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, jqgrid, get

I'm trying to populate a jqGrid from a jQuery.get() response and I'm having difficulty.

I have my have table set up pretty simply and have been able to successfully call my servlet and return the xml through the following setup:

```
$("#table_1").jqGrid({
    datatype : 'xml',
    url : 'QueryServlet?param1=x',
    ...
    // the rest of the options
});
```

So I know the servlet and the xmlReader I have for the grid is correct.  The problem is I need to do some editing of the data before I load it into the grid.  I've tried the following to no success:

```
$.get('QueryServlet",{params}, function(data){

    $("#testdiv").html; //test to ensure the get() call is working properly
    // where i need to edit the data
    $("#table_1").addXmlData(data);  // <-the problem

});
```

I get the following error when I call that:
"Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" code: "3

I feel like I'm not doing something correctly with (data).  I've tried data.element, data.firstChild, data.lastChild.  I'm fairly new to jQuery so I'm sure I'm getting at the xml incorrectly.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what data looks like?

Comment: yes, sorry it took so long to get back to this (was gone for the weekend).  This is the response from the servlet that I see when using Firebug to debug it: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<row>
  <cell>cell1</cell>
  <cell>cell2</cell2>
</row>
<row>
  <cell>cell1</cell>
  <cell>cell2</cell2>
</row>
</root>

Answer (score 0):

[Loading XHTML fragments over AJAX with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156133/loading-xhtml-fragments-over-ajax-with-jquery)